# Duplicate caption and table header with csvsimple and csvreader

Tags: longtable, csv, csvsimple

My CSV file has two headers in the first two rows (first row has static keywords, second row is the header to display) and I am displaying it using `csvreader`. I want to use the second row header as a header row of the table to display. The first page of generated table always has that header, but I also want it to be repeated on the second page of my `longtable`.

Code:

```
\def\tablecaption{Table caption}
\csvreader[
longtable={|c|c|c|},
table head=\caption{\tablecaption}
\label{tab:mytable}
\\\hline \endfirsthead
\caption*{Table~\thetable Continued \newline \tablecaption}
\\\hline
%%%%%%%%%% I want to repeat the second row from csv file here %%%%%%%%%%
\\\hline
\endhead,
late after line={\\\hline},
table foot={},
separator=tab,
]
{mytable.csv}
{}
{\csvlinetotablerow}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can process the csv file with a first reader to store the expanded second line into a macro `\mysecondline`. The second reader (table) can use this for the repeated header.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple,filecontents,longtable}

\begin{filecontents*}{mytable.csv}
staticA,staticB,staticC
headA,headB,headC
A,B,C
a,b,c
1,2,3
A,B,C
a,b,c
1,2,3
A,B,C
a,b,c
1,2,3
A,B,C
a,b,c
1,2,3
A,B,C
a,b,c
1,2,3
A,B,C
a,b,c
1,2,3
A,B,C
a,b,c
1,2,3
A,B,C
a,b,c
1,2,3
A,B,C
a,b,c
1,2,3
A,B,C
a,b,c
1,2,3
A,B,C
a,b,c
1,2,3
A,B,C
a,b,c
1,2,3
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[
  filter test=\ifnumequal{\thecsvinputline}{2},
]
{mytable.csv}
{}
{\edef\mysecondline{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii}}


\def\tablecaption{Table caption}
\csvreader[
  longtable={|c|c|c|},
  table head=\caption{\tablecaption}
  \label{tab:mytable}
  \\\hline \endfirsthead
  \caption*{Table~\thetable: Continued \tablecaption}
  \\\hline
  %%%%%%%%%% I want to repeat the second row from csv file here %%%%%%%%%%
  \mysecondline
  \\\hline
  \endhead,
  late after line={\\\hline},
  table foot={},
  %separator=tab,
]
{mytable.csv}
{}
{\csvlinetotablerow}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I do that with `\csvlinetotablerow` instead of `\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii`? I'm getting a `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. [...\edef\tableheaderrow{\csvlinetotablerow}}]` error...

Comment: @nagimov No, I do not think so, because `\csvlinetotablerow` is somewhat too special to use it like that.

Answer (score 0):

So based on Thomas' answer I ended up with the following snippet:

```
\def\tablecaption{caption goes here}
\def\tablefile{csv file name goes here.csv}
\def\tablelabel{tab:label-goes-here}
\csvreader[separator=semicolon,filter test=\ifnumequal{\thecsvinputline}{2}]{\tablefile}{}{\edef\mysecondline{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv}}
\csvreader[longtable={|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|C{4cm}|},
% **** table setup ****
  table head=\caption{\tablecaption}
  \label{\tablelabel} \\\hline \endfirsthead
  \caption*{\raggedleft\hfill Table~\thetable continues. \newline \centering \tablecaption}
  \\\hline \mysecondline \\\hline \endhead,
  late after line={\\\hline}, table foot={}, separator=semicolon,
]{\tablefile}{}{\csvlinetotablerow}
```

When I want to create a new table, I only need to edit the five lines on top (I decided it's not worth wrapping to a macro).